# jquery Multiple rows change "add new" to "delete" position

Tags: jquery, html

I have using multiple rows by using jquery. Currently, when i click "Add new" button, rows added below the current row and button name changed to "delete". but i need to change the process as followings:
when i click "add new" button, rows added above the current row and button name changed to "delete". 
I need to display “Add New” button to last row, previous rows must have “Delete” button. I couln't add row to above. Please help me if anybody knows.

Here is the fiddle to check
http://jsfiddle.net/tWada/

```
$("input[type='button'].AddRow").live('click',
function() {
    var index = $(this).closest('tr').index();
    if (index > 0) {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();

    } else {


        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr').clone(true);
        $tr.find('img').remove();
        var $input = $tr.find('input.startdatum');
        var index = $('input#counter').val();
         $('#acti_btn').val('Delete');
        var id = 'datepicker' + index;
        index++;

        $('input#counter').val(index);
        $input.attr('id', id).data('index', index);
        console.log(index);
        $tr.prependTo($(this).closest('table'));      

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution now. I have using the below code

```
$tr.find('.AddRow').val('Delete')// set value to Delet
           .toggleClass('AddRow delete')// toggle classes
           .unbind('click'); // unbind the current events from button
```

instead of

$('#acti_btn').val('Delete');

Answer (score 0):

try insertbefore() like mentioned below

```
$tr.insertBefore($(this).closest('table'));
```

you may also need to make some name changes.Docs for insertBefore() are [here](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/).Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks aameer. i have one more doubt. if i change "prependto" to "insertbefore", then the new row will be added above the current row.but newly added rows are displayed in misaligned and also current row button will be changed to delete. how can we rectify? Here is the changed fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tWada/1/

Comment: try it out yourself, if you can't i will check it out in the evening

Comment: i try it. but i couldn't got it. i am not familiar with jquery. pls work me to fix this.

Comment: check out this link (http://jsfiddle.net/tWada/3/) i have updated the  fiddle now tags are fine two issue still are there the css and i noticed on clicking on first delete the div isn't deleted.Will look into it if I get some more time.

Comment: aameer, i apply the css class directly to the "tr". but still not aligned correctly? if u got any idea of this?

Comment: if we use "insertbefore" method, the content element will be moved and not cloned.[refer the site](http://www.learnjavascript.co.uk/jq/reference/manipulation/insertbefore.html) but we need cloned element when click button. other than "insertbefore" method, any function need to work this?

Comment: @NitheesBavesh if you look closely into the fiddle code, you will notice that we first clone the element and the use insertbefore. How else would we have got the replicated elements which are being added on addnew button click.Moreover if you are struggling with this approach alternative way of doing this could be by adding html dynamically directly by something like this $(".some_container_div" ).html('<div></div>'); This way you can directly specify the html you want.Sorry for delays.I will surely take a serious look into it today hopefully in evening.

Comment: aameer, Thanks for your effort. I got the solution. i also post the answer for ur reference.